# What is this code all about? It is hard to interpret

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np 
  
np.where([[True, False], [True, True]], 
         [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 6],
       [3, 4]])
```

What do [True, False], [True, True] mean?

Comment: please understand that StackOverflow is to help you in coding and technical challenges. this is not the kind of question you ask here, you need to search, research, try.

Comment: Look at the docs for `np.where`.  Then examine the three arguments.  They look like lists (of lists).

Answer (score 0):

The first list (with boolean values) determines from which of the other two lists a value will be picked.

So if we align the values vertically, we have:

```
np.where([[True, False], [True, True]], 
         [[   1,     2], [   3,    4]], 
         [[   5,     6], [   7,    8]])
```

Now when the first list has a `True`, then the corresponding value (for the result) will be taken from the first data list (i.e. from [[1, 2], [3, 4]]). If it is `False`, it will be taken from the other list (i.e. from [[5, 6], [7, 8]]).

Let me mark the selected elements with an asterisk:

```
np.where([[True, False], [True, True]], 
         [[  *1,     2], [  *3,   *4]],  # <-- select when True 
         [[   5,    *6], [   7,    8]])  # <-- select when False
```

Hence the result is:

```
         [[   1,     6], [   3,    4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is the **condition**:

```
[[True, False], [True, True]]
```

If True return X, if False return Y.

Second parameter contains the **data** (X, Y):

```
[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

which would otherwise imply `X=[1,2], [3,4]`, `Y=[5,6],[7,8]`.

Iteratively:

- First condition is True, we yield X = 1.
- Second condition is False, we yield Y = 6.
- Third condition is True, we yield X = 3
- Fourth condition is True, we yield X = 4